# Qt repaint permanence

Tags: c++, qt, repaint

I'm creating a simple Paint program in Qt (C++) where you pick a shape and it follows your mouse around on a canvas until you click, at which point that shape locks to the screen at that position. The user can then continue in this manner, adding more and more shapes to the screen. My problem lies in getting these shapes to stay in place after I click. I tried using this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true), but as soon as I set that attribute false again I lose my data. Is there some way I can "lock" the screen so my old stuff stays on it while the new stuff gets overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the painted data, you should draw to a QPixmap first then paint this QPixmap on your widget.